# Jekyll Permalink Configuration

Tags: jekyll

I'm having a hard time configuring permalinks for my blog posts. The way I have my blog set up is root/news/index . 
I set my _config.yml to "./" so all my articles are on the same directory as my news index.html. But whenever I click on my article's permalinks on the news homepage, it redirects me to "mysite.com/article" instead of "mysite.com/news/article". I've also tried "./news/" but it only creates another news folder inside my original news folder. I've also tried the setting "pretty" but it still goes to "mysite.com/.." not "mysite.com/news/..."

Answer (score 2):

In the _config file you can change the permalink to anything you like, for example mine is

```
permalink: /blog/:title
```

As for the date you can choose your own date using the YMAL front matter, again in mine i have

```
title:example date: you can pick what ever date you want
```

So in your case I would try this

```
permalink: /news/:title
```